# Examples of practical usage of Alloy

Tags: alloy

There are different Alloy applications (railway switching, access control, etc). For example, hotel room locking in "Software Abstractions". But how can I implement such model in real hotel?:-) 
Are there some articles or examples of code when Alloy is used in real-life problems?

Thanks!
Vadik.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this thread of discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334256/experiences-with-using-alloy-in-real-world-projects/11994172#11994172